# How to upload my website and databse to the internet

Tags: python, database, upload

I have already developed my web application, but I do not know how to upload it to the internet since I also need to upload my local database. Is there a way to upload my entire web app with the database to Heroku or another hosting service? Do I need to upload my local database to Google Cloud or AWS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im using MySql for the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Heroku - they have great documentation, first, you will configure Heroku Connect in order to synchronize data between your Salesforce org and the Heroku Postgres database, attached to your app - [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-and-connect-without-local-dev#synchronize-data-with-salesforce)

Second, create a Heroku `Dataclip` where it lets you easily share the results of `SQL queries` on a Heroku Postgres database. Because your app now syncs Salesforce data to a Heroku Postgres database, you can make use of Dataclips to easily create multiple public or private views of the data - [the steps here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-and-connect-without-local-dev#create-a-heroku-postgres-dataclip).